# AWS Client VPN Access to Instances in a VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to setup AWS Client VPN so clients can connect and access instances running in a subnet via their private addresses.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/scenario-vpc.html

I followed this guide and had no issues but I couldn't figure out how to actually access the instances. I can connect to the VPN just fine but I can't ping any of the instances with their private adresses.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you change your servers security group(s) to allow traffic from your local network?